# Setting UIActivityIndicator while shifting to another UIview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to display activityindicator in didSelectRowatIndexPath event when iam moving from one UIView to another UiView.It should be displayed as long as the process for loading another uiview takes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code but I am giving example you should modify it & use according to your need:

```
   alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];

                UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

                indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
                [indicator startAnimating];
                [alert addSubview:indicator];
```

Ok after pushing your class use this line to dismiss indicator:

```
 [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Try. Best of luck.